# Script affecting all images instead of only images in div that contains certain text (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filter

I've tried editing this code a number of ways (using if statments and each statements) with nothing working. The idea is so simple; if a div contains this specific text, I want to change the src attribute of the image in that div only.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing. The code below changes all the images in all divs with that class rather than just the ones that contain the specific text. I've tried to work in 'this' but apparently don't understand how it affects the function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my-content').filter(':contains("Top")').find('img').attr("src", "http://www.samplestuff.com/kids/test.png");
});
```

Could someone kindly point me in the right direction of what I need to change to make the script target only images in the div that contain the text instead of all div with that class because one of the div did contain that text (I think that's what triggers it; I may be off about that too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Try this:</del>

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my-content:contains("Top")').find('img').attr("src", "http://www.samplestuff.com/kids/test.png");
});
```

<del>[See jQuery :contains docs](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)</del>

**Edit**
Actually I think your answer should work as well. Seems to work fine in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0yyg7o25/2/), can you post your markup?

```js
$('div').filter(':contains("Top")').css("color", "red")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Top</div>
<div>Right</div>
<div>Bottom</div>
<div>Left</div>
```

Comment: I really thought so too! But nope--still changes all images in divs with that class name.

Comment: May have been a cache issue; yours works; don't know what is affecting the filter function? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what the cause could be on that one; latest library and everything.